# Bitbucket pipelines not showing content of environment variables

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

```
image: python:3.7.3 

pipelines:

  branches:
    Server:
    - step: 
       name: Test
       script:
          - echo $MYTEST
```

My pipeline shows this:

```
echo $MYTEST

+ echo $MYTEST
$MYTEST
```

The variable is a "Repository variable" and is named MYTEST

I have done the same process with a *node* image and it is working fine. Because this is a python project i took python, but the environment variables don't seem to work.

I suppose, i cannot use a pure python docker image, if i need some bash commands, correct?

Comment: Hello, can you make sure the variable is not set as "secured"? Otherwise bitbucket hide the value.

Comment: I am facing similar issue. I defined same variable in repository variable and in environment variable with different values. but I am always getting repository variable value. I verified correct branch name in bitbucket-pipeline.yaml as well